# CodeIgniter .htaccess RewriteRule result in 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I used the following `.htacces` to route from an old page to a new one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Uploader2.7.0/secureFileUploader.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /uploader/upload [L,QSA]
```

Even though the rewrite rule is correct, I got a *'404 page not found'* error. This `.htacces` is at the root of my site.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752609/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-but-why#answer-3769389), I changed:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And that made the reroute rule work fine, but the CLI stopped working. Then I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677314/running-codeigniter-via-cli-outputs-website-root-instead-of-expected-result#answer-7713974) which says it will work if I will change the *'uri_protocol'* back to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Is there a way to make both work?

**Note:** the rewrite rule works, the issue is with the CodeIgniter internal routing. I can make it work either with the `RewriteRule` rule or with CLI, not both.

**EDIT:**

I want the url `/Uploader2.7.0/secureFileUploader.php` to become `/uploader/upload` internally, which i managed to do using the rule above.

`/uploader` in the path of Codeigniter `index.php`, and `upload` is the name of the controller I wish to route to.

Under `/uploader` I have the `.htaccess` file to hide the `index.php` of CodeIgniter, which works perfectly:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: When the requested URI is `/Uploader2.7.0/secureFileUploader.php` you want it to be internally rewritten to `/uploader/upload` only ? Or to `/uploader/upload/something_else` ? Please tell what **exactly** are urls for **old** and **new** pages

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear, i've added the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

put your .htacces file at same level of application, user_guide folder.
So u have total 6 file in your codeigniter folder including index.php and license text document as well as .htaccess file.

[image: This image is useful for you]

Comment: That's the setup i am using. .htaccess rerouting works fine, codeigniter works perfectly, the issue is with the CLI and the codeigniter internal routing

Comment: Okay, I thought that your .htaccess code is going well.