# How to call CodeIgniter Controller as Cron Job

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to call a Codeigniter controller through a cron job. But something is going wrong, I am not getting the desired result. I tried to access the same controller through the PHP CLI and instead of returning the output that the controller should return, it outputs the contents of the project homepage. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677314/running-codeigniter-via-cli-outputs-website-root-instead-of-expected-result) has a similar problem.

My crontab has the following entry:

```
22 13 * * * php /var/www/html/projectfolder/index.php cronJobGmutrrPdt runJobForUpdatingClgRevConnSummary
```

But this is not working, so I tried to run it through the CLI:

```
php /var/www/html/projectfolder/index.php cronJobGmutrrPdt runJobForUpdatingClgRevConnSummary
```

In this case the CLI runs but instead of outputting the controller's output it outputs the contents of the default controller that is the project homepage.

Comment: What controller are you calling? It seems you are just requesting index.php and in that case it would not be strange that you get a output of the standard controller. Have you tried `/var/www/html/projectfolder/index.php/mycontroller/method/` ?(try this with the cli first)

Comment: "cronJobGmutrrPdt" is the controller and "runJobForUpdatingClgRevConnSummary" is the function

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have register_argc_argv disabled in your php.ini file. This is why the direct php script works. Since a cronjob runs like a CLI command you will need this enabled to pass arguments.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Take a look at this php document above and it should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Did it but sad to say it didn't help me. Same result getting homepage as output instead of the controller i called P.S i added register_argc_argv in the php.ini that is at location /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and not in apache2 and cgi folders, Is it correct or shall it be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked:

```
/usr/bin/php  -f /var/www/html/projectfolder/index.php mycontroller method
```